# how to specify bigint data type when creating btree index on jsonb in Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a jsonb column with field   time_in_seconds.
Most queries against that table will be asking to sort the result set with time_in_seconds (largest value first).

If I simply do

```
create index t_mytable_timeinseconds__idx ON t_mytable using btree ((mycolumn->>'time_in_seconds'));
```

Postgres creates an alphanumeric index (which will not result in correct sort order).

But i cannot seem to figure out how to instruct postgres to treat the values as bigint  in descending order.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use casting in indexes.

Normally you would cast json like that: `(json_value->>key)::bigint`, otherwise you would cast your `key` to bigint and it would throw error.

So this gives as 3 sets of parentheses - one for index, second for index expression and third for casting.

```
create index t_mytable_timeinseconds__idx
ON t_mytable
using btree ( ( (mycolumn->>'time_in_seconds')::bigint ) );
```

Comment: thank you. The explanation also helped me to figure out where to add the DESC  specifier.  create index t_mytable_timeinseconds__idx
ON t_mytable
using btree ( ( (mycolumn->>'time_in_seconds')::bigint ) DESC );

Comment: Postgres will do Index Scan Backward if index order is in reverse of what query wants - for the same cost, so no need to do that, but of course it won't hurt either.